# Calculate the time difference between two datetimes

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I need to calculate the hours between the current datetime and the one that a user selects from a dropdown field.
In my form here (https://www.cosmostravel.gr/affiliate/hotel/luxembourg/en/) when someone selects Return Trip from the ONE WAY or RETURN field he gets promted to input DEPARTURE DATE (pick_up_time) & RETURN DATE (return_pick_up_time). I get the hours difference between the two dates using the following code:

```
$date_pickup = new DateTime($options['pick_up_time']);
$date_return = new DateTime($options['return_pick_up_time']);
$diff_return = $date_return->diff($date_pickup);
$hours_return = $diff_return->h;
```

Now the $hours_return is exactly the time difference in hours that I get and it works fine!
The problem is that when I have the following code for the pick_up_time it doesn't give me the number of hours between the current datetime and the pick_up_time

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');
$current_date = date('d/m/Y H:i', time());
$date_pickup = new DateTime($options['pick_up_time']);
$diff_pickup = $date_pickup->diff($current_date);
$hours_pickup = $diff_pickup->h;
```

Further down in my code I try to check if the $hours_pickup is less than 12 hours but $hours_pickup is not a number to be able to do the comparisson.

```
if ($hours_pickup <= 12) {
$total_fare = 0.00;
$can_book = false;
}
```

Since $hours_return gives me the correct number in hours for the datetime difference between return_pick_up_time & pick_up_time, I think that the problem relies on the $current_date value which I have checked that is in the same format as the $date_pickup but still it doesn't work.

What is wrong with my code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: isn't it that `$current_date = new DateTime()` gets the current time too? why not use that instead

Comment: Let's see. The [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/datetime.diff.php) method takes a [`DateTimeInterface`](http://php.net/manual/class.datetimeinterface.php) as its first argument. [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/function.date.php) returns a string. Do you see the problem?

Comment: I used $current_date = new DateTime() but it seems that it doesn't take into consideration the date or the 24hrs of the day. i.e. if current date/time is 04/06/2018 08:00 and I select 05/06/2018 00:00 the difference should be 16 hrs. It gives me 7 hrs! If I select 06/06/2018 08:00 the difference should be 48 hrs. it gives me 0 hrs. How can I correct that?

Comment: Also, I see that DateTime::diff() is a string but in the case of :
$date_return = new DateTime($options['return_pick_up_time']);
$diff_return = $date_return->diff($date_pickup);
$hours_return = $diff_return->h;
Which is also a string it works fine. Why it does it here???

Comment: ANY IDEAS ON WHAT I SHOULD USE? You need more info?? THANKS ! !